# Please, how do I enlarge the <i> element when I hover on its parent element <div>. I've tried the code below but it's not working

Tags: javascript, css

Please, how do I increase the size of the  element in the . I've tried this but it's not working.

```
 <script>
function enlarger(){
document.getElementsById('enlarge').style.transform="scale(1.5)";
}
</script>


<style>
#enlarge{transition:transform .2s;}
</style>


<div onmouseover="enlarger()">
<i class="fa fa-desktop color"id="enlarge"></i>
<h2 style="font-size:150%; color:green"> Digital Capacity Development</h2>
<p style="text-align:justify;">This  is a paragraph text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` (*singular*). Also, why not just do it through CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pure CSS.

```
div:hover i {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: `div:hover #enlarge` would make a better selector.

Comment: Thanks so much @Gavin and BenM. That worked perfectly. But I want to know what's probably wrong with the Javascript integration. I feel it can also work with Javascript. Thanks in advance

Comment: About the javascript, as mentioned by BenM above, it should be `document.getElementById`, not `document.getElementsById` because the function will return a single item.